# Apache 2 using Include with full path

Tags: windows, apache, configuration, apache2

I'm attempting to set up a test environment where the software is being developed on host machines then tested in a Virtual Machine and the VM has all code mapped to a `Z:/` drive. My issue is that Apache is complaining and won't start up saying that I have an invalid `Include` path of Z:/source/myconf.conf. Anyone have luck previously of setting conf files up in a different different drive path that can help me understand what I'm doing wrong? I've tried with and without quotes as well.

Include path statement:

```
Include "Z:/source/myconf.conf"
```

Additional info:

Z is a virtual drive through VMWare also known as `\\vmware-host`

The specific error in the Application logs is as follows:

```
The Apache service named  reported the following error:
httpd.exe: Syntax error on .. of C:/.../httpd.conf: Invalid Include path Z:/source/myconf.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like its finding issue connecting to the Z drive and as z is the network drive, it must require user name and password which is creating issue

solution 
If we can save the user name and password so that it won't ask for user credential dbl clicking to z drive.

To save permanently the user credential 
Open command prompt and type 
"net use Z: \servername\sharename /persistent:yes /savecred"

Now restart and see it should not ask user credential to connect to z drive and the apache error won't be there.